# Proving $\int x \, \mathrm{d}y =xy- \int y \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to justify formally that

$$\int x \, \mathrm{d}y =xy- \int y \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Background: I don't know how to work with the $\mathrm{d}y, \mathrm{d}x$ and for me it's just a symbol for the variable of integration.

Comment: I guess $y=y(x)$?  Then $dy=y'(x)dx$.  Then use the regular integration by parts, which is proven from the product rule.

Comment: don't understand why it was downvoted 4 times. whatever.

Comment: Several members have had sticks up their butts lately about questions that don't show any work.  This is just a simple question about an idea, rather than a calculation, though.  In fact, this idea is a little subtle and the answer to this could potentially help others.  So personally I don't see any good reason to downvote.

Comment: @Bye_World Exactly. Many calculus courses do not teach the theory behind the infinitesimals and therefore I believe that my question is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

Try differentiate $xy$ by the product rule first:

$$\frac{\text{d}(xy)}{\text{d}x} = y + x\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$$

Then integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$xy = \int y\ \text{d}x + \int x \ \text{d}y$$

And then re-arrange the equation:

$$\int x \ \text{d}y = xy - \int y\ \text{d}x$$

Comment: I don't understand the second step. Why $\int y + x\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} \text{d}x = \int y\ \text{d}x + \int x \ \text{d}y$. Are the $\text{d}x$'s cancel each other?!

Comment: Both terms on the RHS are being integrated. To the first term, just add the $\int$ in front and $dx$ after. To the second, do the same, but the $dx$'s cancel out so that $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\text{d}x=\text{d}y$. So, yes, the $\text{d}x$'s cancel out.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ might look like a straightforward fraction, but it's not. You can't simply cancel $dx$'s without further justification.

Comment: @DanPiponi: Yes, I do believe there are some epistemological considerations to take into account when dealing with infinitely small quantities. I don't have a good explanation as to what limits might surround my claim that the $\text{d}x$'s 'cancel' out, but do you have one, or a reference?

Answer (score 0):

It essentially follows from the rule for differentiating a product.  Let's do it formally, since that seems to be where your confusion lies.  Let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the set of all Riemann integrable functions on $[a,b]$.

Claim: If $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are differentiable and $f',g'\in\mathcal{R}$, then $\int_a^bf(x)g'(x)dx=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_a^bf'(x)g(x)dx$.

Proof: Differentiability $\implies$ continuity $\implies$ integrability, and so $f,g\in \mathcal{R}$.  Since the product of Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrable, the products $f'g$ and $fg'$ are also in $\mathcal{R}$ and both integrals exist.  By the rule for differentiating the product of differentiable functions, $(fg)'(x)=f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)$ everywhere (i.e. $fg$ is an antiderivative of $f'g+fg'$).  Since the antiderivative of a Riemann integrable function differs from the indefinite integral by a constant, $fg$ differs from $f'g+fg'$ by a constant.  Hence for all $t\in[a,b]$ we have

$f(t)g(t)-f(a)g(a)=\int_a^t[f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)]dx=\int_a^tf'(x)g(x)dx+\int_a^tf(x)g'(x)dx$.

Setting $t=b$ gives the desired result, finishing the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ be two differentiable functions. Then, from the product rule,

$$[f(t)g(t)]' = f'(t)g(t) + f(t)g'(t).$$

Integrating both sides we get,

$$\int [f(t)g(t)]' \; dt = \int f'(t)g(t) \; dt + \int f(t)g'(t) \; dt,$$

$$\implies f(t)g(t) = \int f(t)g'(t) \; dt + \int f'(t)g(t) \; dt.$$

Let $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$, which gives $dy = g'(t) \; dt$ and $dx = f'(t) \; dt$. Then our equation becomes

$$xy = \int x \; dy + \int y \; dx$$

Rearranging the terms, we get

$$\int x \; dy = xy - \int y \; dx.$$

Answer (score -1):

Taking $\;\int\;$  as what it actually is, namely antiderivative (the name "indefinite integral" is one of the worst *ever* in mathematics, imo), and assuming $\;y=y(x)\implies dy=y'(x)dx\;$ , we get integrating (i.e., antidifferentiating)  by parts, with

$$\begin{align}&u=x&,\;\;u'=1\\{}\\&v'=y'(x)&,\;\;v=y(x)\end{align}\;\;\;\;\implies$$

$$\int x\;dy=xy(x)-\int y(x)\,dx$$